# What PHP Functions Create Output?

Tags: php

Has anyone ever compiled a list of all the PHP functions/methods that send output to the browser (or STDOUT when running in CLI mode)?  A quick search didn't show any manual pages with this information (but I could be wrong there)

I'm interested in functions that are designed to do this, not functions that may raise warnings that would be sent directly to the browser.

The `print` and `echo` functions are the obvious ones, I'm looking for a list of lesser known output functions, like [readfile](https://www.php.net/readfile).

The main reason I'm asking the question is I'd like a list of functions to check for when tracking down "early output" style errors. (headers can't be set, etc.)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding list:

```
printf
vprintf
var_export
passthru
gzpassthru
fpassthru
debug_print_backtrace
```

[+] they are rather obvoius but also worth mentioning:

```
flush
ob_flush
ob_end_flush
```

And header related functions also produces output, I remember having to run php-cgi, when CLI binary was not available, and there it was especially annoying

```
header
setcookie
session_start /* with sessions that uses cookie */
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `curl_exec()` with setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to false.

And are `die()` and `exit()` good enough for your list?

Edit: `imagepng()`, `imagejpeg()`, `imagegif()`?

And actually `phpinfo()`.

Comment: _And actually phpinfo()_ - and [`phpcredits()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpcredits.php).

Answer (score 1):

Have never seen a list, but can add `var_dump` and `print_r` for starters? :)

Answer (score 1):

There's one which is often overlooked / eschewed:

```
trigger_error()
```